# View Isilon ACLs from Linux as ordinary user

Tags: linux, isilon

I have an Isilon mount that's mounted as NFSv3 on RHEL. There are some Active Directory groups that are used in access lists. I have a folder where those ACLs are applied. When I open the folder properties in Windows and go to Security tab, I can see those groups, with appropriate permissions. As a non-root user without access to Isilon itself, is there a way to view those groups from within a Linux client?